# How to use ViewModels in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I just started learning about ViewModels in ASP.NET MVC. So, I thought of implementing a sample example as below:

**Business Entity**

```
public class AddModel
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }

    public int Add()
    {
        return (this.a + this.b);
    }
}
```

**Add ViewModel**

```
public class AddViewModel
{
    public AddModel addModel;
    public int Total { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class AddController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Add(AddViewModel model)
    {

        int iSum = model.addModel.a + model.addModel.b;
        model.Total = iSum;
        return Json(model);

    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**View Implementation**

```
@model ViewModelApplication.AddViewModel
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Callback(data) {
        alert("I am sucess call");
    }

    function Failed() {
        alert("I am a failure call");
    }
</script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Add", "Add", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "Callback", OnFailure = "Failed" }))
{
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td class="tdCol1Align">
                <label>
                    Number1</label>
            </td>
            <td class="tdCol2Align">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.addModel.a)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tdCol1Align">
                <label>
                    Number2</label>
            </td>
            <td class="tdCol2Align">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.addModel.b)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="submit" value="Add" class="button" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

The problem here is that I am unable to retrieve the values entered into the text boxes whenever the `Add` button is clicked; the corresponding AJAX action is being it.

When I try to access the values of `a` and `b`, I get nulls instead of the values entered into the text boxes.

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Please help.

Comment: Do you see the expected values in the form collection? I'm not quite sure, but since your doing an AJAX-postback I believe you model is being serialized when you do a postback. The controller might not recognize it anymore as a viewmodel, but sees it as an collection of posted values. But again, i'm not sure this is what is happening..

Comment: @Rob..yes i could see the values in the form collection

Comment: In general it's not a good idea to include the Model as part of the ViewModel.

Comment: @haim770..i agree with you..but what is the alternative to it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your view model should look like this

```
public class AddViewModel
    {
        public int a { get; set; }
        public int b { get; set; }
        public int Total { get; set; }
    }
```

and in the cshtml

```
            <td class="tdCol2Align">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.a)
            </td>

            <td class="tdCol2Align">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.b)
            </td>
```

in the controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Add(AddViewModel model)
        {
            int iSum = model.a + model.b;
            model.Total = iSum;
            return Json(model);

        }
```

**Edit**

View model is there to render your views don't place any logic inside that. if you have more complex model then it will be hard to map `Model` with `ViewModel`. for this you can use AutoMapper or ValueInjector for mapping between model and view model.

link for automapper http://automapper.codeplex.com/

link for value injector http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/

hope this helps

Comment: @Anto..what if u have 20 fields..in the domain model..and i want all of them along with 5 other fields..

Answer (score 5):

You should not use the domain (business) entities in your view model. If you do, a view model is pretty useless since it stills contains business logic which you might not want in the view. The model in your example doesn't really represent a real-world scenario, a view model is not really needed for it anyway.

A more common and trivial example of a view model is a login form: You probably have a domain model called `User` and you want them to log in. The `User` domain model can be big and just a small part of it is needed for the authentication. It also contains validation logic for the database which doesn't represent validation logic for the login form.

The `User` domain model:

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(36)] // The password is hashed so it won't be bigger than 36 chars.
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public string SalesRepresentative { get; set; }

    // etc..
}
```

The above domain model represents the database table thus containing validation logic to ensure integrity.

```
public class LoginModel
{
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please fill in your user name.")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please fill in your password.")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

The view model above contains just the properties we need for the login form and has it's own data annotations. This helps you to cleanly separate view logic and business/data logic.

Comment: ..Thanks for the explanation . But , what if my domain model contains 20 fields and i need 2 more extra fields. Do, i need to put all those fields in the view model which are already there in Domain model..

Comment: @Henk..in my example , view model can be needed in the case where we do not want to create anonymous object while sending back results to view(Example - total in my scenario)

Comment: @Avinash yes sometimes view models are a copy of domain models with, but usually they contain other validation attributes and contain data annotations for display names etc. My personal experience is that I always get in trouble when using domain models in my view.

Comment: @Avinash with a domain model as simple as in your example, you _could_ use it directly in your view. In other words: it's not a good test case for practicing with view models and understanding why you need them.