# Using WebAPI and MVC, is it a good idea to have separate return models for extensibility?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I came across this question when returning a model(**Object1**) with several dependencies via an IEnumerable<**Object1**> with REST.

I suddenly realized I may not want to return all this information, and was wondering if I should re-think **Object1** itself, or make a ***ReturnObject1***, which only contains the essential information I need.

Comment: This is very similar to the use of a View Model instead of a Model when dealing with a View. Often times your underlying model may have chained objects that you don't need to return to either the View or in your case the API response. A View Model, or as you termed it "ReturnObject" is the ideal way to go to limit the information returned. You could use LINQ and select an anonymous object as a return result too if you wanted to.

Comment: @NickBork, thanks, that cleared things up.  I am familiar with MVVM, but didn't think about it until you mentioned it.  This link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323713/how-to-use-viewmodels-in-asp-net-mvc] also helped to distinguish when to use ViewModels

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's better to keep all request/response objects in 'contract' DLL for you REST. And yes - you have to do mapping between 'contract' model and 'internal' model in your controller.
Is this case all changes for 'internal' model will be hidden from applications calling your REST.