# Have Required Attribute apply to property in one view and not another?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Say I have a class called Test and I have a Create and Edit view.  Say this class is incredibly simple

```
public class Test
{
    [Required]
    public string str { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to remove the required attribute when a user is editing this object?

Comment: asp.net mvc, other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**ViewModels**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3) are there for this. One for **Create** and one for **Edit**.

You should use a ViewModel for this, as you need View Specific Models here :

```
public class CreateTestViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string str { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
public class EditTestViewModel
{
    public string str { get; set; }
}
```

You might want to read about [**What is ViewModel in MVC**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc) and [**How to use ViewModel in MVC**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323713/how-to-use-viewmodels-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: If EditTestViewModel Inherited from CreateTestViewModel, could you override str without it being required, or is the proper solution here to just separate the classes entirely?

Comment: they should be separate, no inheritance :)